# How to remove Linear Layout via code in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a Linear Layout with many linear layouts inside. At runtime , I want to remove this layout(along with its child linear layouts) from the view subject to a condition. On removal, I want other layouts to be adjusted accordingly.

I tried this, but the layout remains.

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("ListingType").equals("Brief")){
            extraLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            extraLayout.removeAllViews();
        }
```

This Activity has 2 main Linear Layouts, 1 is DetailsLayout and 2 is ExtraLayout, both these layouts are relative to each other in a ScrollView. The main(root) layout of the Activity is Relative Layout

Comment: Set visibility gone of Parent `LinearLayout` in xml .

Comment: what is `extraLayout` ?

Comment: also, are you sure that the if condition is called?

Comment: boolean b=(getIntent().getStringExtra("ListingType").equals("Brief"));  try to print the log of b and check whether its value is true

Comment: Check the added info in the edits

Comment: Ok but how have you declared extraLayout in your java class?

Comment: post your xml and activity code.

Comment: @Lal, obviously I have, otherwise I would have got an error at defining the extraLayout

Comment: ok..are you sure that the if condition is called?

Comment: second option put `else` and inside it put `log`. then check out logcat.

Comment: can you put your whole xml code?

Comment: Yes, the if condition is being called.

Comment: post your xml please